# PYTHON: How to perform set of instruction at predefined time

Tags: python, time

I have a set of instructions, say {I} and I would like to perform this set {I} 
at predefined time for instance each minute. 
I'm not asking how to insert a delay of 1 minutes between to successive executions of 
the set {I}, I want to start the instructions {I} each minute independently of the time of execution of {I}.

If I inderstand the following code

---

```
import time

while True:
   {I}
   time.sleep(60)
```

---

would simply insert a delay of 60 secs between the end of the execution of {I} and the following one. Is it true? Instead I would like that the set of instructions {I} starts each minute (for instance at 9.00 am, 9.01 am, 9.02 am, etc).

Is it possible to perform such a task inside python, or is it preferable to write a script with {I} that I execute each minutes, for instance, with Crontab?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Unless you have very specific needs, crontab seems easier and more reliable, so...

Comment: Are you asking about the Python sched module?  http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html

Comment: What does your program actually do at these intervals?

Comment: basically download a webpage and extract a piece of information

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [`signal.alarm`](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#signal.alarm) and [`signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)`](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#signal.signal) should help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need finer resolution than a minute, cron would be the easiest option. Otherwise you'd end up re-writing something like it.

If you need intervals shorter than a minute, you might consider "timeouts" from the [glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/) library. It has Python bindings. The timeout should then probably start the task in a separate process.

Answer (score 2):

Something like [APScheduler](http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/) might meet your needs. 
I'm sure there are other similar packages out there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, you'd have to instantiate separate threads for every instruction to be run concurrently, and simply dispatch them in your delayed while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could spawn a thread every second using [threading.Timer](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects):

```
import threading
import time

def do_stuff(count):
    print(count)
    if c < 10: # Let's build in some way to quit
        t = threading.Timer(1.0, do_stuff, args=[count+1])
        t.start()

t = threading.Timer(0.0, do_stuff, args=[0])
t.start()
t.join()
```

Using the [sched](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html#module-sched) module is another possibility, but note that the `sched.scheduler.run` method blocks the main process until the event queue is empty. (So if the `do_stuff` function takes longer than a second, the next event won't run on time.) If you want nonblocking events, use `threading.Timer`.